# A simple question about the indentation problem in txt

Tags: python, append

```
def sav_dic(self):
    f2 = open('my_dic.txt', 'a')
    for j in range(len(re_doc2)):
        f2.write(re_doc2[j]+':'+def_lst[j])
    f2.close()
```

Above is a function within a class. Also, the content is already written in my_dic.txt.

```
A:Contents of B
B:Contents of B
```

I want to add content through the above function. But there was a problem here. I'm going to add the contents from C to E. The ideal situation I hope for is as follows.

```
A:Contents of B
B:Contents of B
C:Contents of C
D:Contents of D
E:Contents of E
```

However, if I use the above function, it comes out as follows.

```
A:Contents of B
B:Contents of BC:Contents of C
D:Contents of D
E:Contents of E
```

I tried writing an escape code again, but this time it comes out like this.

```
def sav_dic(self):
    f2 = open('my_dic.txt', 'a')
    for j in range(len(re_doc2)):
        f2.write('\n'+re_doc2[j]+':'+def_lst[j])
    f2.close()

A:Contents of B
B:Contents of B
C:Contents of C

D:Contents of D

E:Contents of E
```

I'm quite bothered by this. How can solve this?

Comment: Are you open to suggestions on how to store your data in a reasonable way?

Comment: You'd need to read the last character from the file and check if it's a newline, and write one if it's not…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a '\n' before you write new lines to f2.

```
def sav_dic(self):
    f2 = open('my_dic.txt', 'a')
    f2.write('\n')
    for j in range(len(re_doc2)):
        f2.write(re_doc2[j]+':'+def_lst[j])
    f2.close()
```

Thanks for Matthias' comment. You can write it in this way:

```
def sav_dic(self):
    with open('my_dic.txt', 'a') as f2:
        f2.write('\n')
        for x, y in zip(re_doc2, def_lst):
            f2.write(f'{x}:{y}')
```

Comment: You made me escape from hell of assignment by your escape code!
Really thx!

Comment: And you might want to change this unpythonic index access with something like `for value1, value2 in zip(re_doc2, def_lst):` followed by `f2.write(value1 + ':' + value2)` (or `f2.write(f'{value1}:{value2}`). Of course you should replace `value1` and `value2` by more meaningful names.

Answer (score 1):

You can only write the newline for the first line you write

```
for j in range(len(re_doc2)):
    if j == 0:
        f2.write('\n')
    f2.write(re_doc2[j]+':'+def_lst[j])
```

Or update the code that writes `my_dic.txt` to always end lines with `\n`

Comment: Thank you for spending your precious time on me. Really thx!